# Código de JavaScript no se ejecuta

Tags: javascript, scroll

espero y me puedan ayudar con el siguiente problemita que tengo.

Tengo un codigo 'sencillo' de `JavaScript` el cual lo unico que hace es detectar `scrollY`, esto con el fin después de desarrollar una lógica; ejemplo:

```
let posicionInicial = 0;
let _nav = document.querySelector('.navbar');
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    posicionInicial = window.scrollY;
    if(posicionInicial > 0){
        _nav.classList.remove('sticky-top')
        _nav.classList.add('fixed-top')
    }else{
        _nav.classList.add('sticky-top')
        _nav.classList.remove('fixed-top')
        
    }
    console.log(`eventListener: ${posicionInicial}`);
});
```

Incluso lo hice con `onscroll` para detectar `scrollY`;

```
window.onscroll = () => console.log(`onScroll: ${window.scrollY}`);
```

#### Problema

El problema está en que niguno de los códigos antes puesto funciona en mi desarrollo, es decir, no muestra los `console.log()`. Lo puse dentro de las etiquetas `<script>` y nada lo puse en un `.js` separado y nada.
Sin embargo en cualquier otro archivo (html o php) si funciona, incluso lo probé en **Code SandBox** y funciona [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/scrolling-dylrh3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Alguna ayuda al respecto, gracias.

Comment: 1) Prueba poner todo dentro de `addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => { //aqui dentro });` -- 2) Verifica que no exista otro error en algún otro código

Comment: @Yussef Tampoco se ejectua, intente con un `window.` y un `document.` y tu ejemplo y nada incluso lo he intentado con funciones autoinvocadas `(()=>{})()` o `(function(){})()`, y tampoco. Incluso si pongo un `log` de **posicionInicial** si lo imprime pero no todo lo demás.

Comment: Es que el código es correcto (yo también lo probé), por lo tanto descarta que el problema esté ahí, por lo que tienes que buscar en otra parte.

Comment: Quizá si agregas más información sobre tu desarrollo podríamos detectar algo.

Comment: Puedes revisar que si hay espacio para hacer scroll en la ventana? Si no hay espacio para hacer scroll el evento no se va disparar, por ejemplo, tu ventana puede tener un alto de 500px, pero el navbar y el contenido, esta dentro de ese limite, no hay evento scroll al que escuchar

Comment: @caprilo básicamente lo que se quiere hacer es lo que se ve en el primer código con el nav

Comment: @AugustoM si hay espacio de hecho configure el height a  100 vh, y agregue varios divs en otros ejemplos que he realizado, y se puede hacer el scroll cómo se ve en el sandbox. Pero ya en mi desarrollo de producción pues nada más no se ejecuta

Comment: no se si te sirva pero lo q hice para solucionar el error fue en la etiqueta <script> agregar el defer para que se ejecute también cuando lea todo el contenido de html y pueda ejecutar el proceso

Answer (score 0):

La variable que empieza por barra baja no puede empezar por dicho carácter...

```
let posicionInicial = 0;
let first_nav = document.querySelector('.navbar');
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    posicionInicial = window.scrollY;
    if(posicionInicial > 0){
        first_nav.classList.remove('sticky-top')
        first_nav.classList.add('fixed-top')
    }else{
        first_nav.classList.add('sticky-top')
        first_nav.classList.remove('fixed-top')
    
    }
    console.log('eventListener: ${posicionInicial}');
});
```

Comment: Estaría bien que explicaras el motivo y sería una buena respuesta.

Comment: Ninguna variable en javascript puede empezar por números o guiones bajos...

Comment: Hola @PolFlórezViciana de hecho si puedes utilizar guiones bajos, te dejo esta [referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types)

Comment: Veo que si se puede y yo tenia entendido que no, así el fallo puede estar en el punto del navbar en la propiedad querySelector .